# Как извлечь из всех введенных предложений все слова, содержащие заданное буквосочетание на Си?

Tags: c

Задание звучит так:
Разработать функцию, которая извлекает из предложения первое слово, содержащее заданную комбинацию символов, и возвращает адрес конца этого слова. С клавиатуры введите несколько предложений и буквосочетания. На основе разработанной функции извлечь из всех введенных предложений все слова, содержащие заданное буквосочетание. Напечатать результат извлечения.

Вот что уже имею:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int i = 0, k = 0;
char sentences[20][100], search[20];
 
void Input(void);
void Find(char search[]);
 
 
int main() {
    system("chcp 1251");
    Input();
    Find(search);
    return 0;
}
 
void Input() {
 
    printf("Введите к-во предложений:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    rewind(stdin);
 
    printf("Введитье %d предложений:\n", k);
 
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        gets_s(sentences[i]);
 
    }
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("Введите буквосочетание:\n");
    gets_s(search);
}
 
void Find(char search[]) {
    int coinc = 0;
    printf("\n");
 
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (strstr(sentences[i], search)) {
            printf("%s\n", sentences[i]);
            coinc++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nСовпадение %sнайдено.\n", (coinc > 0) ? "":"не ");
}
```

Comment: `возвращает адрес конца этого слова` - это точно? Конец слова будет или пробельный символ или нулевой символ конца строки. Как-то плохо вяжется с задачей `извлечь из всех введенных предложений все слова`. Напечатать результат извлечения - это собственно слова или адреса на конец этих слов?

Comment: @Laukhin Andrey результатом дожны быть именно слова.

Comment: Тогда для чего функция должна возвращать адрес конца найденного слова? И где в приведённом коде эта функция?